# How to reference an other indicator from pine script?

Tags: pine-script

I have bought premium indicators and oscillators.
I would like to write a pine script in TradingView that depends on the values, colors of these.

How can we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use source type input in any indicator

```
src = input(close, title="Source")
```

Then in the settings panel you can feed any other indicator output to this.
And, you can use this src for any calculation.